# How to add a new language into Vim's spelling files?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

Vim's [default spell languages](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/) doesn't contain Turkish language. How can I add a new language to Vim's spelling dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the fine manual: `:h spell-mkspell`. Also here is a thread on the vim users list: http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg05334.html